# Building node contextify using Visual Studio 2013

Tags: node.js

I'm attempting to get "contextify" to build on my machine. It is a Windows 10 machine.

I am using Windows 10

I have Visual Studio 2013 Professional installed.

I have python 2.7.10, and it's in my PATH.

I have node 4.1.2 32 bit installed (I had previously tried with 64 bit, which is the default that the node website wanted me to download, but it appears to make no difference).

I've got no idea what the right sequence of steps should be, I don't know anything about node-gyp, npm etc, I'm just trying to build a project that has a dependency on contextify.

I've done a clone of the contextify repo from git hub and naively run
  `npm install'. I'm using a Visual Studio command prompt (either VS2013 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt or VS2013 x86 Native Tools Command Prompt, makes no difference).

What I get is this:

```
d:\work\contextify>npm install

> contextify@0.1.14 install d:\work\contextify
> node-gyp rebuild


d:\work\contextify>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\tomq\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
  contextify.cc
d:\work\contextify\node_modules\nan\nan.h(263): error C2995: 'v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Local<T>)' : function te
mplate has already been defined [d:\work\contextify\build\contextify.vcxproj]
          d:\work\contextify\node_modules\nan\nan.h(256) : see declaration of '_NanEnsureLocal'
d:\work\contextify\node_modules\nan\nan.h(661): error C3083: 'smalloc': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type
 [d:\work\contextify\build\contextify.vcxproj]
d:\work\contextify\node_modules\nan\nan.h(661): error C2039: 'FreeCallback' : is not a member of 'node' [d:\work\contex
tify\build\contextify.vcxproj]
d:\work\contextify\node_modules\nan\nan.h(661): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'FreeCallback' [d:\work\contexti
fy\build\contextify.vcxproj]
d:\work\contextify\node_modules\nan\nan.h(665): error C2065: 'callback' : undeclared identifier [d:\work\contextify\bui
ld\contextify.vcxproj]
d:\work\contextify\node_modules\nan\nan.h(665): error C2065: 'hint' : undeclared identifier [d:\work\contextify\build\c
ontextify.vcxproj]
d:\work\contextify\node_modules\nan\nan.h(672): error C2665: 'node::Buffer::New' : none of the 4 overloads could conver
t all the argument types [d:\work\contextify\build\contextify.vcxproj]
          C:\Users\tomq\.node-gyp\4.1.2\include\node\node_buffer.h(43): could be 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> node::Buff
  er::New(v8::Isolate *,char *,size_t)'
          C:\Users\tomq\.node-gyp\4.1.2\include\node\node_buffer.h(31): or       'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> node::Buff
  er::New(v8::Isolate *,v8::Local<v8::String>,node::encoding)'
          while trying to match the argument list '(v8::Isolate *, const char *, uint32_t)'
d:\work\contextify\node_modules\nan\nan.h(676): error C2664: 'v8::Local<v8::Object>::Local(const v8::Local<v8::Object>
&)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>' to 'const v8::Local<v8::Object> &' [d:\work\contextif
y\build\contextify.vcxproj]
          Reason: cannot convert from 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>' to 'const v8::Local<v8::Object>'
          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be cal
  led
d:\work\contextify\node_modules\nan\nan.h(683): error C2039: 'Use' : is not a member of 'node::Buffer' [d:\work\context
ify\build\contextify.vcxproj]
d:\work\contextify\node_modules\nan\nan.h(683): error C3861: 'Use': identifier not found [d:\work\contextify\build\cont
extify.vcxproj]
```

I have read the [Contextify Windows Install Guide](https://github.com/brianmcd/contextify/wiki/Windows-Installation-Guide), but it doesn't really help me. I have read many other posts as well.

Am I supposed to be able to get this to compile using Visual Studio 2013?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've got same issue.

I've solved this problem.
Contextify is not supported in node 4.x.
So I've downgrade node to 0.10.x, then works fine.

Alyosha.

Comment: Hurrah! Thank you, that was the info I needed.